# Javascript not working after server upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, dreamhost, gsap

Like the title says, I just finished building a website. Tested it on my local server where everything works perfectly without any errors.

However, after uploading my files to the dreamhost servers, the site loads but my animations and interactivity are not working. I contacted the customer service and was told that in my error.log file it says the folder where all my GSAP.js files are located cannot be found. But looking at my panel, all files were uploaded successfully.

In order to be sure it was not just the dreamhost servers, I decided to try uploading the site to github servers and still the same thing. The site and all files uploaded successfuly but the javascript files are not running or located. I don't know exactly. And after looking at the console and the network in the google developer tools, there is no single error, it shows all files were uploaded successfully as there is no error.

What may be causing this issue? I'm lost.

Here is the code referencing all GSAP.js and my index.js files

```
<script src="Resources/js/index.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/js/Draggable.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/js/ThrowPropsPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/js/MorphSVGPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/js/SplitText.min.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/js/CSSPlugin.js"></script>
<script src="Vendor/js/ScrollToPlugin.js"></script>
```

Here is my folder structure

- about.html
- case-studies.html
- contact.html
- contact.php
- css folder
- experiments.html
- images folder
- index.html
- PHPMailer folder
- Resources folder
- Vendor folder

The vendor folder contains all the js files as you can already tell.

Comment: Are you using absolute paths? Can you post the relevant code that references the "GSAP.js" files along with the directory structure that you are using?

Comment: When you visit the hosted site, check your browser console. Some CSS files might be failing to load, or it might have errors that shed some light on the problem. (You did mention the console in your question but I'm not sure if you're checking when uploading the files or when visiting the site).

Comment: @kshikama I just edited the question to provide the details you requested.

Comment: @Sidney I checked everything and all files were loaded. There were no errors whatsoever. I checked the console when visiting the site after uploading all files to the dreamhost servers. I don't see how I can check the console when uploading files. If you wouldn't mind, I could give you the link to the site.

Comment: send your live website link

Comment: Here is the link - www.seimodei.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your files loaded correctly .. The problem here

```
function setupPage() {
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  switch(filename) {
    case 'index.html':
      setupIndex();
      break;
    case 'about.html':
      setupAbout();
      break;
    case 'contact.html':
      setupContact();
      break;
    case 'case-studies.html':
      setupCaseStudies();
      break;
    case 'experiments.html':
      setupsetupExperiments();
      break;
   }
}
```

you already `substring` the url to find the page .. but actually you didn't set anything if the url doesn't have any page in url

That mean if you go to http://www.seimodei.com/index.html  your website will work as expected

so you need to check the `filename` before switch .. you can use

```
var forcheck = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var filename = (forcheck.indexOf('.html') !== 1) ? 'index.html' : forcheck ;
```

OR redirect to `index.html` *I don't recommend this*

```
var forcheck = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var filename = 'index.html';
if(forcheck.indexOf('.html') !== 1) {
     window.location.href = "http://www.seimodei.com/index.html";
}else{
     filename = forcheck ;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seems to be the issue. So how do I make sure the page loads directly to the index.html on each visit?

Comment: @user8930909 try to `console.log(filename )` and open `www.seimodei.com` directly and see what you'll get

Comment: you can use .htaccess or you can create index.php in your root `<?php header('location: index.html');?>` . Last: dont forget to check this as an answer

Comment: @plonknimbuzz Thanks. I will try that that and see how it goes.

Comment: @user8930909 answer updated .. check the two line codes for `forcheck` and `filename` .. simply the code check for `.html` if not it will return the `index.html`

Comment: @Mohammed-Yousef After trying your code, the pages seem to no longer load with errors popping up in the console - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: @user8930909 no its not related with my code .. It's related with your code which always assume there is always page on url .. BTW wait for updating answer .. I'll try to redirect your page to `index.html` on start

Comment: @Mohammed-Yousef  Ok let me try it now.

Comment: @Mohammed-Yousef  Everything works now after the redirect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mohammed-Yousef  Sorry for being a bother but redirecting the URL to itself creates a loop and so the website freezes.

Comment: @user8930909 to be honest redirect not the right solution .. the best solution is the previous one .. so try to use the previous solution then try to fix any errors comes from another functions